# Use a string from an else string and display it in a different view

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uiview

I need help displaying a string, If the If-Else statement shows else, in a different View Controller. I am relatively new, so sorry if it seems stupid to you. I tried that in the ViewControler.m File:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    [self.InputField resignFirstResponder];
    if (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"teacher"])
    {
        _Correct.hidden = FALSE;
        _Hider.hidden = TRUE;
        _FalseHider.hidden = FALSE;
        _SHOWCORRECT.hidden = TRUE;
        _CorrectAnswer.hidden = TRUE;
    } else {
        _FalseHider.hidden = TRUE;
        _Correct.hidden = TRUE;
        _SHOWCORRECT.hidden = FALSE;
        _CorrectAnswer.hidden = TRUE;

        NSString *ElseLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"teacher"];
        self.OutputLabel.text = ElseLabel;
    }
}
```

The `Elselabel` is in a different ViewControler in the MainStoryboard…. And when I go there via a modal segue, it doesn't display anything! Thanks for all responses!

Comment: FYI - It is standard practice to begin class names with uppercase letters and to begin method and variable names with lowercase letters. Following standard conventions makes your code much easier to read.

Comment: And in Objetive-C, `BOOL` variables should be set to either `YES` or `NO`.

Comment: When and where are you triggering the modal segue ?

Comment: It's connected to a button.

Comment: Could you please try by replacing the `true` with `TRUE` and `false` with `FALSE`?

Comment: and also, are you sure the else part is executing?

Comment: is the `ButtonTouched` code above the action for the same button that you use to trigger the segue ?

Comment: Yes. The part is executing. I did replace all of the with TRUE and FALSE, or YES and NO... Didn't work....

Comment: Are you using the same button in tha above code for segueing?

Comment: If I am correct, the general understanding is to use segues to move to another viewController. You have mentioned in your question that you are _segueing to a different view via a modal segue_.

Comment: What I suggest is for you to put the `OutputLabel` in a different viewController and segue to that viewController instead.

Comment: Or, alternatively, try this: set the output view as a sub view of the same view controller and hide the subview initially in your viewDidLoad. Write the code to show the subview in your button click action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through these steps

1. go to Appdelegate.h and add a NSString like this

   @property (nonatomic,retain)    NSString *lableString;
2. go to Appdelete.m and synthesize string

   @synthesize lableString;
3. Then change your function like this // don't forget to #import "AppDelegate.h"

   ```
   -(IBAction)ButtonTouched:(id)sender
   {

   [self.InputField resignFirstResponder];
   if (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"teacher"])
   {
   _Correct.hidden = FALSE;
   _Hider.hidden = TRUE;
   _FalseHider.hidden = FALSE;
   _SHOWCORRECT.hidden = TRUE;
   _CorrectAnswer.hidden = TRUE;
   } else {
   _FalseHider.hidden = TRUE;
   _Correct.hidden = TRUE;
   _SHOWCORRECT.hidden = FALSE;
   _CorrectAnswer.hidden = TRUE;

   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   appDelegate.lableString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"teacher"];

   }
   }
   ```
4. and in your different view use this

   ```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   self.OutputLabel.text = appDelegate.lableString;
   ```

not :- it's not best approach but it will surely give you a small lesson

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, where do i do step number 4? I have basically two View Controllers and one ViewControler.h and .m file...

Comment: So all of the above code is in a file i called Tester.m, there's no Viewcontroller.m… shall i create a new file, and if yes, how to connect it?